# How does " Sparsity of connections" in CNNs causes the network to have less parameters?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, cnn, convolution, convolutional-neural-network

I am studying Andrew NG's lectures on Convolutional Neural Network and he had provided two reasons for CNNs having less parameters compared to Non-Convolutional networks . They are :

1. Parameter Sharing
2. Sparsity of connections .

While I can make sense of the first reason causing CNN to have less parameters . I don't understand why Sparsity of connections , that is , " Each output in a layer comes from a small number of inputs " cause the network to have less parameters .

Isn't the second reason a bit redundant ?

Can someone please explain ?

Answer (score 1):

In fact these involve different aspects of parameters in a CNN.

1. Parameter sharing, means one parameter may be shared by more than one input/connection. So this reduces total amount of independent parameters. Parameters shared are non-zero.
2. Sparsity of connections means that some parameters are simply missing (ie are zero), **nothing to do with sharing same non-zero parameter**. Parameters in this case are zero, ignored. That means that **not necessarily all (potential) inputs to a layer are actually connected to that layer**, only some of them, rest are ignored. Thus sparsity of connections.

Answer (score 1):

*Andrew Ng is making this point in comparison to a simple Neural network.*

Let's say you have a 10x10 image,

In a dense neural network,

 - We will connect every 100 neurons to the 100 in the next layer.*(Dense)*

 - Over that, each all will have a distinct weight *(No sharing)*

So, total *parm = 10K*

In a Convolution Neural Network, the approach is as shown in this image,

[image]

Now,

**Weight sharing** - The kernel will have the same weight for each pixel in the next layer *i.e. it will not have distinct 9 weights for each slide.*

**Sparsity** - The pixel at the next layer is not connected to all the 100 from the first layer *i.e. only a local group is connected to one pixel of next layer*. It is not trying to get information from the full image every time. *We are harnessing the properties of an image that a group of near-by pixels has better info than grouping distant pixels*

So, total parm(*definitely size, number, and stride of the kernel will control it*)

> With a 3x3 kernel,
>
> (3 * 3) + 1 per kernel = 10 per kernel
>
>  *Even with 200 kernels, it will be only 2K as compared to 10K*

Answer (score 0):

In the convolution layer of the convolutional neural network (CNN), each output value depends on a small number of input values, known as the sparsity of connections.

In neural network usage, "dense" connections connect all inputs.

By contrast, a CNN is "sparse" because only the local "patch" of pixels is connected, instead using all pixels as an input.